# Can a creature that is immune to magic be affected by a spell that ignores spell resistance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, immunities, spell-resistance

In D&D 3.5 and/or Pathfinder if a creature is immune to magic, does a spell that has "SR: No" affect it ?

I ask cause technically its a spell and is magic, but of course spells that don't allow SR usually create an effect that is not magical itself.

Comment: Did you have a specific creature in mind? The answer to this question may differ from creature to creature.

Answer (score 12):

Probably yes. In general when a creature is immune to magic, the text of the ability says it only applies to things that allow spell resistance. For example, the text on the [pathfinder flesh golem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-flesh) ability "immune to magic" reads:

> A flesh golem is immune to any spell or spell-like ability that allows spell resistance.

Even the *spell immunity* spell only grants "unbeatable spell resistance" to the spells the target is immune to.

Comment: important note - this is true only for pathfinder flesh golem. There seems to be no *general* rule about that, each monster with immunity gets it's own entry that might be different. Or not. For D&D, there is an entry in SRD, but it still notes that each creature may have more detailed info.

Comment: The same thing Molot said goes for the spell "Spell Immunity", it is a specific rule, but there seems to be no general rule that should apply to "Magic Immunity". Each entry has their own exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

### No.

The [Universal Monster Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules) defines [Immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Immunity-Ex-or-Su-) like this:

> **Immunity (Ex or Su)**
>
> A creature with immunities takes no damage from listed sources. Immunities can also apply to afflictions, conditions, spells (based on school, level, or save type), and other effects. A creature that is immune does not suffer from these effects, or any secondary effects that are triggered due to an immune effect.
>
> Format: Immune acid, fire, paralysis; Location: Defensive Abilities.

But in general, Yes.

The abilities that [golems in general](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-iron) got is called **Immunity to Magic**, and behave different from the universal monster ability:

> An iron golem is immune to **spells or spell-like abilities that allow spell resistance**. Certain spells and effects function differently against it, as noted below.

For those creatures, all spells that does not allow [spell resistance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Spell-Resistance-SR-) affect them as if they had no immunity at all. Also, each golem type has a different set of spells that can affect them, regardless of their immunity (listed on each golem's entry).

As far as i know, there is no creature that is Immune to Magic without an exception, but if the specific creature's entry did not mention *except those that allow spell resistance*, by the definition on the Universal Monster Rules, the creature would be immune to all Supernatural, Spell-like and Spells based on Magic.

Answer (score 1):

In pathfinder, [Immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Immunity_Ex_or_Su) and Immunity to Magic are two different things. Immunity to Magic is not defined in the universal monster rules, but per creature.

If you take a monster with Immunity to Magic, it is affected by spells (or spell-like effects) without spell resistance. Each creature has a specific entry with exceptions and notes.

Immunity (to magic in general) doesn't exist in pathfinder, and in general wouldn't make much sense. If you have complete immunity, your own magical effects wouldn't work on you (any *Su*, *Sp*, or similar effects, including those from magic items). Do damage or magical abilities work on (or for) you? Vorpal? Can you use wands? IMHO, no.

But, the only monster with immunity (that is official and I can remember) is D&D 3.5e's [demilich](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/demilich.htm). In pathfinder, this monster was [changed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/demilich/). IMHO, pathfinder version make more sense.

Comment: (Even in *3.5e* [the demilich's magic immunity didn't make a whole lot of sense](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60092/8610).)

Answer (score -3):

### A creature with immunity to magic IS affected by spells that ignore it.

Immunity to Magic is usually Spell Resistance that always succeeds, Thus spells with "SR: No" bypass spell resistance in the same way that spells with "Save: None" do not allow you to roll a saving throw.

Comment: The question wasn't whether "SR:No" bypasses *resistance*, but whether it bypasses *immunity*

Comment: @Adeptus I guess I wasn't clear but in case you weren't aware the way Magic Immunity works is that creatures with it auto pass spell resistance checks.

Comment: The way spell immunity works is the heart of this question, and this answer is still really unclear.