# Ha-Naga spells save DC

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, difficulty-class, epic-tier

I'm preparing an encounter with an Ha-Naga, and I'm surprised by its spells save DC.

According [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/haNaga.htm), its saves are 33 + spell level, charisma-based ; but it has "only" 36 charisma, which should put its save at 23 + spell level.

Or it's only the chaos/evil spells that have a +10 to DC ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No explanation's given in the *Epic Level Handbook* (195), the [*Update Booklet*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a), or the *SRD* for the [ha-naga](http://dndsrd.net/epicNonAbominations.html#ha-naga) receiving that +10 to its spells' saving throw DCs.

And, to this reader, it seems that the ha-naga, as written, receives that substantial bonus to *all* of its spells rather than *only* to those spells from the domains Chaos and Evil. That is, the ha-naga's spells description says

> Ha-nagas can cast spells as 21st-level sorcerers, and can also cast cleric spells and spells from the domains of Chaos and Evil as arcane spells (save DC 33 + spell level). The DC is Charisma-based.

Further, while the ha-naga spells description in the *Epic Level Handbook* omits the final sentence, it's otherwise identical. The ha-naga, it seems, is naturally, repeatedly, and inexplicably awesome at spells.

(Although straying significantly beyond the texts *and* inviting speculation, keep in mind that it's entirely possible that the ha-naga's enhanced saving throw DC is just a repeated error—mistakes <strike>happens</strike> happen both in the *Epic Level Handbook* and the *SRD*'s nominal *3.5* update of its epic monsters. I've posed a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60092/8610) or [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48398/8610) about the [demilich](http://dndsrd.net/epicNonAbominations.html#demilich) and a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90378/8610) about the [leShay](http://dndsrd.net/epicNonAbominations.html#leshay) myself after trying to use those creatures as written.)

#### If those save DCs are too high, consider instead the Faerûnian ha-naga

*Serpent Kingdoms* describes the Faerûnian ha-naga (75–6) that largely possesses traits identical to the original ha-naga except that it has DR 15/epic and that the saving throw DCs against Faerûnian ha-naga's spells are computed normally (i.e. DC 23 + spell level). This might be a better choice to throw against a party of PCs with less than stellar saving throw modifiers.

Comment: (Note that this answer is in no way an endorsement of using *Serpent Kingdoms* in its entirety! Although by *Serpent Kingdoms*' standards, the Faerûnian ha-naga is rather tame, caution should nonetheless be exercised when introducing *Serpent Kingdoms* material into a campaign.)